# What is name used for in url path?

Tags: django

I am new to django and have this in my `urlpatterns`:

```
path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
```

I don't understand the significance of putting `name='bio'`. What does this do? Thanks!

Comment: I did found response on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922641/what-is-the-function-of-the-name-parameter-in-django-urls-path

Comment: I did found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922641/what-is-the-function-of-the-name-parameter-in-django-urls-path

Comment: I did found the response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922641/what-is-the-function-of-the-name-parameter-in-django-urls-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That allows you to use something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'bio' username %}">go to bio/{{username}}</a>
```

in the template.  For more useful ideas, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is there anything else that they can be used for?

Comment: Sure: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Answer (score 0):

You use the name to refer to your particular view, for example now in your template you can do the following:

```
{% url 'appname:bio' %}
```

Note the following from the documentation:

> When naming URL patterns, choose names that are unlikely to clash with
> other applications’ choice of names. If you call your URL pattern
> comment and another application does the same thing, the URL that
> reverse() finds depends on whichever pattern is last in your project’s
> urlpatterns list.

You can see more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is there anything else that they can be used for?