# purpose of argument name="home" in django path definatioin

Tags: python, django

I write a path in Django with an argument name and with its value home to display a simple HttpResponse.

`path('',views.home, name='home')`

My question is why we use `name="home"` while writing a path.

Comment: Go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19171674/8353711) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922641/what-is-the-function-of-the-name-parameter-in-django-urls-path) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In short, keeping a name makes it easier, if you want to specify which url you are supposed to go to after clicking a button, or which url you want to redirect to after finishing an operation. So instead of typing out the whole url, you can specify the name and it will take you to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this section of documentation [See Naming URL patterns for why the name argument is useful.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

The name argument is used to perform URL reversing, for example in your tests or in a template file.

```
# define some path :
path("index/", views.index, name="main-view")

# use url name to reverse it in a template:

{% url 'main-view' %}
```